# How can I make a stack panel with a transparent background and blur effect in WPF without an image?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have only found solutions to this question that work with images, but I want to be able to overlook a stack panel with this "effect", for example. I actually want it to look something like the one in Windows, for example, like here:

[image: Picture1]

so that you can see a slight transparency in the background.

Comment: `StackPanel Background="Gray" Opacity="0.9">`

Answer (score 0):

This kind of translucent texture is called [Acrylic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/acrylic?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) and is a Fluent Design System component on Windows 10.

If you want to bring this kind of brush to your app, I would recommend you to look into using the [WinUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/windows/apps/winui?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) library. This is the modern and native user experience (UX) framework for Windows desktop applications going forward.

WinUI 2.x controls be used WPF applications using [XAML Islands](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/xaml-islands?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077).

WinUI 3 is the next version of WinUI that includes a full native UI platform that can be used on top of the latest version of .NET and be seen as a replacement for WPF and WinForms GUIs.

There is no native support for Acrylic in WPF.